# iOS & Adobe AIR working together

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I know I can wrap native iOS code within an Adobe AIR application: Adobe calls it Native Extensions, which leverages native iOS API to offer features that Adobe AIR does not have. 
My question is, what about the opposite way? Is there a way to wrap ActionScript/Adobe AIR code within a native iOS application? I know this is difficult, but I guess there must be some way. 
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Why, in heaven's name, would you want to do this? The whole reason for iOS Native Extensions is to give AIR access to otherwise inaccessible bits of iPhone/iPad mobile hardware. What does AIR or AS3 have that iOS wants?

Comment: @Craig Let's say, I have a quite big AIR app, and I want only one or two features from native api, then I will go for native extension for sure. But what if I have a quite big iOS native app, and I only want a bit from AIR?

Comment: Well, what KIND of a bit? If you'd gone to the trouble of writing a big native app for iOS, what could you add in AIR that you COULDN'T add by updating the iOS app's native code? Just curious.

Comment: Actionscript only functions within Flash or AIR, you would need something in your iOS code that acts as a Flash/AIR Player. I dont believe such a thing exists. In theory you could push this some form of webview, but I doubt there is anything in the iOS SDK that renders SWFs. As Graig says, it would probably better to address what you need from AS by finding an equivalent in iOS Native

Comment: @Craig Well, I have a RED5 there so I want to make a RTMP connection. I am aware that there are ios-rtmp libraries, but I just want to know whether I can achieve this by AIR.

Comment: @CyanAngel I agree that iOS seens not have a way to render SWFs in sort of a webview. I know Android can accomplish this, but it seems Apple just refuses to open the door for Adobe.